# add auto generate column with correlated subqueries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a column that auto generates value depending on other tables. There are 2 tables to work with.

Table "finance" :

```
revenue | d 
1       |2020-07-01
2       |2020-10-02
3       |2020-01-09
```

Table "price" :

```
price | d
1     | 2020-10-01
2     | 2020-10-02
3     | 2020-10-03
4     | 2020-01-08
5     | 2020-10-09
```

And by executing this command

```
select p.*,
(select f.revenue * 10 from finance f where f.d <= p.d order by d desc limit 1) revenue_X_10
from price p
```

I get this result

```
price | d         | revenue x 10
1       2020-10-01    10
2       2020-10-02    20
3       2020-10-03    20
4       2021-01-08    20
5       2021-01-09    30
```

I wanted to make the revenue_x_10 auto generated by doing something like this.

```
ALTER TABLE price 
ADD COLUMN revx10 FLOAT
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (select 10*f.revenue from finance f where p.d > f.d order by d desc limit 1) from price p;
```

But looks like I can only put columns from the same table then calculate new ones on them. How can I make the revenue_x_10 as a column generated automatically on the "price" table.

Reason why I want to do something like this is because performance issues. I’m working with relatively big dataset, like a couple thousand row on the "price" and dozen rows on the "finance". And sometimes I need to do this for couple thousand tables. By using queries it's just too slow to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by gordon, it can not refer to other tables while it comes to auto generate.

You can create a view with `not exists` as follows:

```
create view v_price as
    select p.*,
           f.revenue * 10  as revenue_X_10
      from price p 
      join finance f on f.d <= p.d
     Where not exists 
         (select 1 from finance ff Where ff.d > f.d and ff.d <= p.d)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I get performance boost from this? Reason why I do this is not to make subqueries when I select data from it.

Comment: Yes, not exists ans join are genearlly faster than the subqueries in select.

Comment: Which one is ff? I changed the inner one to ff but it only show 1 result instead of the entire column

Comment: Now it should give the proper result.

Comment: Yea this is faster than using subqueries. Took less than half the time

Comment: Replacing the where not exists with comparing timestampdiff will make this even faster. Done it in about 1/10 of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  A generated column can only refer to values in the same row, constants, and non-volatile functions.

What you can do is to use a view:

```
create view v_price as
    select p.*,
           (select f.revenue * 10
            from finance f
            where f.d <= p.d
            order by d desc limit 1
           ) as revenue_X_10
    from price p;
```

Or perhaps an `insert` trigger so the value is calculated whenever you insert a new row.

Comment: Does a view offer any practical advantage over what the OP currently has?

Comment: Thanks! Is the performance a little better than using a select? I‘m working with a lot of data and the reason I wanted to do this is to store the data so that  I don't have to do the subqueries everytime I select it.

Comment: @MonSh1rE . . . A view would have the same performance.  You can create a trigger if you want to summarize the data for performance reasons.